# Real time chat implementation for SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, chat, real-time

I have a client interested in a real time chat application for a SharePoint intranet portal to enable online interview style chat sessions.

Has anyone got reccomendations for a product on the Microsoft Stack that does this? Something that is integrated into SharePoint would be prefferable, but any ASP.NET product would suffice.

The solution would need to be pretty robust as we would expect over 1000 users during a given session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft Office Communication Server](http://www.microsoft.com/uc/products/ocs2007.mspx) is the way Microsoft intended chat for SharePoint. I dont know if its just for 1 to 1 communcation or if there is a good multi-user support.

Another way to implement chat (or IM) in SharePoint is to use Windows Live Messanger and the green precense icon which shows up to the left of all names in SharePoint. But this is probably not the way you want to use chat.

Answer (score 0):

We initially turned to handy Windows Live Messanger, However we dropped it because of security concerning.

We are using Groove, which look advisable so far.

FYI

Answer (score 0):

There is [ChatterBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/05/15/chatterbox-persistent-chat-session-for-sharepoint.aspx). It's more of a demo app but the source code is available. The [latest version](http://cks.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5021) is dated 2007 and is in beta with AJAX support.

As you have the source code, I'm sure you could take it and turn it into something nice.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little work into this but dropped it because it take alot work to implete all needed features. 
The easiest way looked to use IRC.  IRC client software is available as asp.net, use via an iframe or make into a custom web part, there are also flash or java clients which could be imbedded.

You would need to setup a IRC server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third party product for SharePoint 2010 called [GameTime](http://zaanglabs.com/products.aspx) that supports real-time web based chat integrated into SharePoint.